# Rails - Check if item is in the last 15 entries of database

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to Rails and SQL and having issues about this particular problem...

I have a database 'Item' containing 'items' added by users, with three columns:
- one is a **string with the name ':name' of the item** 
- one is a **foreign key for the category of the item ':category_id'**
- the last is **a string containing the IP adress of the user ':ip'** who added the item.

(There is also a timestamp).

I would like to check if the IP of the current user is somewhere in the last 15 entries of database for the current category.

I've been struggling with the right selector in the item controller, to select the value of the "IP" column for the last 15 entries for the correct category_id. An example of what I tried :

```
@last_fifteen_ip = Item.select("ip").last(15).where(category_id: params[:id])

user_ip = request.remote_ip

if @last_fifteen_ip.include?(user_ip)
  flash[:success] = "User is in the last 15 IP"
end
```

Doesn't work at all... maybe because @last_fifteen_ip doesn't select only the IPs so I can't use .include? correctly...

Thank you very much if you can help me.

Comment: Do you get any error or do you get the wrong records?

Comment: @last_fifteen_ip return an array but not the one I want :

[#<Item id: nil, ip: "127.0.0.1">, #<Item id: nil, ip: "127.0.0.1">, #<Item id: nil, ip: "127.0.0.1">]

Comment: I think you got the answer, try @miler350 answer.

Comment: Make sure you specify an explicit `order`. As a general rule of thumb, if the order of your SQL query matters, specify it explicitly. Different OS & database combinations (like development vs. production environments) will use different default ordering. So, if you want the last fifteen IPs by created_at, then do `Item.where(category_id: params[:id]).order(created_at: :desc).last(15).pluck(:ip)`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip ! I'll be sure to note that.

Comment: For the record : I just corrected as you said but it appears pluck have to be placed before "last". It doesn't work if I put pluck at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like your `@last_fifteen_ip` is returning an array of IPs, which is what you want.

Try this:

```
@last_fifteen_ip = Item.where(category_id: params[:id]).pluck(:ip).last(15)
```

This should return an array of IPs. That would make your `.include?` query work.

Comment: It works perfect ! I didnt knew this .pluck method at all. Thank you very much !

Comment: I'm about to write this :)